# Remove bullets from the Clipboard data while copying from Word

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i have a requirement to remove bullets while copying from MS Word.
I have some code to replace them with list tag in HTML.
But i want to remove instead of replacing them with lists.
Please someone help me, Below is my code   But it is not Javascript code.I need it in Javascript

```
 Find and Replace '•\t.+', '<li>\0</li>', 'EaW'
 Find and Replace '•\t', '', 'EaW'
 Find and Replace '</li>(?=(?:.|\n)([^<]+)|\z|(?:.|\n)\z)', '</li></ul>', 'EaW'
 Find and Replace '(?<!</li>\n)<li>', '<ul>\0', 'EaW'
```

Thank you

Comment: What programming language is that code in? It's definitely not JavaScript.

Comment: @Matt Ball Thanks for your response.. That is not javascript code, But i need it in Javascript for my application.

Comment: @Jaitsu Ha ha ha  come on yaar :-)

Comment: Have you actually made an attempt to write some code? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example of what you are trying to do.  I leave it to you to write the rest and make sure it works.

```
var bullettedText = "•  asdf";
var html = bullettedText.replace(/•\t/g, '<li>');
alert(html);
```

This one replaces all matches of `•\t` in the text with `<li>`.